# Clear dynamic controls from dynamically created panels

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, dynamic

I have the following program in winforms:
[image]

I Want to clear the two buttons you see in the panels.

The code that I have seems to only clear the last button in the last panel. I need to clear all panels. What am I missing here:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Panel pnl1;
        Panel pnl2;
        Button btn;
        private void createPanels(int spacing)
        {
            pnl1 = new Panel();
            pnl1.Location = new Point(5, spacing);
            pnl1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pnl1.Size = new Size(85, 93);
            this.Controls.Add(pnl1);

            pnl2 = new Panel();
            pnl2.Location = new Point(91, spacing);
            pnl2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pnl2.Size = new Size(85, 93);
            this.Controls.Add(pnl2);

        }

        void addCons()
        {
            btn = new Button();
            btn.Size = new Size(40, 20);
            btn.Location = new Point(5, 5);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addCons();
            createPanels(5);
            pnl1.Controls.Add(btn);

            addCons();
            createPanels(99);
            pnl1.Controls.Add(btn);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnl1.Controls.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: Do **not** use Controls.Clear(), check the edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason only one panel is clearing is because you're reassigning the value of the `pnl1` variable each time you call `createPanels`. Avoid using global `Panel` variables here and consider storing the panels in a list.

```
//class level variable
List<Panel> allPanels = new List<Panel>();

//...   

Panel pnl1 = new Panel();
//...panel code
this.Controls.Add(pnl1);
allPanels.add(pnl1);

Panel pnl2 = new Panel();
//...panel code
this.Controls.Add(pnl2);
allPanels.add(pnl2);

//..
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Panel p in allPanels) {
        while (p.Controls.Count > 0) p.Controls[0].Dispose();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could iterate through all the controls on the form and get the `Panels` like that but using a list gives you more control and potentially avoids having to iterate through lots of controls.

Comment: You gave *very* poor advice, Control.Clear() causes a permanent leak.  Fixed.

Comment: @HansPassant Apologies, I hadn't realised `Control.Clear` doesn't remove it from memory. Thanks for the fix.